# What types are expected from stacked dot notation?

Tags: ats

Consider:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

fun plus_int_int(x: int, y: int): int = x + y

symintr .plus
overload .plus with plus_int_int

implement main0() =
        println!("4+4+4 = ", ((4).plus(4)).plus(4))
```

This works, and it's clear that it can't be `4.plus()` as the `4.` is taken as a float. What I'd like to know is, why doesn't `(4).plus(4).plus(4)` work? ATS finds no valid overload for the second `.plus`, which tells me that it's expecting some other type than `(int, int) -> int`. What type is it expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current ATS2 parser interprets

`(4).plus(4).plus(4)`

as

`((4).plus)((4).plus)(4)`

I cannot easily fix the parser. I will think about it when implementing ATS3.